# Angular 5 ngx-permissions is deleting all permissions on page refresh....How to avoid deleting permissions?

Tags: angular

[image: permissions after login]

[image: permissions after refresh deleted]

**after page Refresh Permissions are empty**
How to avoid deleting of permissions after refresh

Answer (score 1):

If you want data to persist across sessions, you can use the browser's [`LocalStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) API.

To add an item,

```
window.localStorage.setItem("permissions", JSON.stringify(this.permissions));
```

To retrive it,

```
this.permissions = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("permissions"));
```

To remove an item,

```
window.localStorage.removeItem("permissions");
```

You can inspect the localStorage items in Chrome Developer tools, Under *Application>Storage>Local Storage*

**NOTE:** This method fails if cookies are not enabled.

**PS:** I wouldn't recommend storing permissions in LocalStorage, it's better to fetch them from an API call.

Comment: so, in each every component's ngOnInit() method we need to get the permissions from localstorage and use this.permissionsService.addPermission();to store permissions on page refresh

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do it, Or you can also read from localStorage only once in AppComponent and store it in a service so that you don't have to do it in every component's ngOnInit.

Comment: can you please tell me how to store in a service..becauseI am very new to angular 5

Answer (score 1):

Add request in AppModule to retrieve permissions after every refresh

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxPermissionsService } from 'ngx-permissions';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'app';

   constructor(private permissionsService: NgxPermissionsService,
               private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const perm = ["ADMIN", "EDITOR"];

    this.permissionsService.loadPermissions(perm);

     this.http.get('url').subscribe((permissions) => {
       //const perm = ["ADMIN", "EDITOR"]; example of permissions
       this.permissionsService.loadPermissions(permissions);
    })
  }
}
```

more here: https://github.com/AlexKhymenko/ngx-permissions/wiki